# Is there a way to have a function that returns the argument as a string in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, customtkinter

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def get_var(input):
    input.get()

entry_var = ctk.StringVar()
entry_box = ctk.CTkEntry(
    root,
    textvariable = entry_var
    ).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

submit_button = ctk.CTkButton(
    root,
    text = "Submit entry",
    command = get_var(entry_var)
    ).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

.get() isn't recognized unless I use a stringvar from tkinter. I'm clueless as to why.
Could anyone educate me and help me understand?

Is there no way to accept the argument as the tk.stringvar? or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: *".get() isn't recognized unless I use a stringvar from tkinter"* - what do you mean by *".get() isn't recognized"*?  What did you use before *StringVar* is used? Also `command=get_var(entry_var)` will execute `get_var(entry_var)` immediately, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: I meant that def get_var(input) doesn't allow the input to use the .get() method. The .get() method is considered unknown until I use a defined StringVar. I also thought that command executes when button is clicked, I did not know that.

Comment: That's why I asked in my past comment *"What did you use before StringVar is used?"*.

Comment: I'm not using anything but StringVar, but what I want to do is pass a ctk.StringVar as a parameter in the get_var() function

Comment: It should be OK using `ctk.StringVar()`.  What is the error when you tried to use `ctk.StringVar()`?

Comment: You are currently *calling* `get_var` when you create the button, not passing a function for the button to call. Try `CTkButton(..., command=lambda: get-var(entry_var))`, or more simply, `CTkButton(..., command=entry_var.get)`. (Note that `get_var` has to *return* the value `input.get()` produces, not simply call the function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with CustomTkinter, but it vanilla tkinter the geometry manager methods `grid`, `pack`, and `place` all return `None`. As written, your widgets are evaluating to `None` and therefore won't respond to `get()`. Also, `input` is a reserved word for the `input` function - you should use another name here.

You also need to modify the `command` argument for `submit_button`. As written, it's going to call `get_var` immediately, which isn't what you want. You can avoid this by using a `lambda` or by modifying `get_var` to just call `entry_var.get()` directly (this is my preferred approach, since you don't have to pass in the `entry_box` widget).

```
def get_var():  # no need to pass in the widget
    return entry_var.get()  # just call 'get' directly
    # you'll probably want to do something with the value other than just 'return'
    # it, but this is an example...


entry_var = ctk.StringVar()
entry_box = ctk.CTkEntry(
    root,
    textvariable=entry_var
)
entry_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0)  # do this on a separate line

submit_button = ctk.CTkButton(
    root,
    text="Submit entry",
    command=get_var,  # pass the function by name here, no parens ()
)
submit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)  # do this on a separate line
```